# How can two clients on a network (A&B) negotiate a random number N, such that neither A nor B can know the value of N beforehand?

Tags: security, random

The scenario:

```
Suppose two clients A and B are connected over some network.
A and B are playing a strategy game.

Both A and B have all the information of the current state of the game and
both know all circumstances when the game is won, lost or drawn.

Both players are making a move at the same time and inform the other about it.
```

Now assume the move of player A reaches player B, before B has send off his move.
Now, theoretically, player B could change his move in his favor to win this game.

How can the exchange of the moves be changed, such that player B cannot cheat like described above?

---

The described task above is equivalent to negotiate a random number N between two clients A and B, such that neither A nor B can force N to be a specific number.

Does someone know a solution to my problem?

Comment: This may be simplistic, but could they send their moves to each other encrypted, and when they receive the others' move they could send the key. This would require a new key every move.

Comment: No, that would not solve it. Suppose both have send their encrypted moves. Now, A sends his key first and B can get A's move. Now depending, what move A made, B calculates a key, such that B will win, when A uses that key to decrypt B's move.

Comment: It is typically a design feature of ciphers that it be infeasible to calculate a key that can be used to decrypt a given ciphertext to a chosen message. (Ciphers for which this is feasible are vulnerable to a known-plaintext attack.)

Comment: The only other possibility would be for each party to send their moves to a trusted 3rd party.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you are describing can be solved by the use of a [cryptographic commitment scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme); such a protocol can be used to negotiate a random number by having both parties commit to a random number, then XOR those numbers together. A number of such schemes exist, with somewhat different properties with regard to their *binding* (that is, how easy it is for one of the parties to change the value they committed to) and their *concealing* (that is, how easy it is for one of the parties to determine what value the other one committed to).

Comment: Cryptographic Commitment schemes seem to tackle my problem (the english Wikipedia even gives a similar exemple as I did); the only problem I have here is, that in order to implement a fair game for A and B, I would need a commitment scheme that is both perfectly binding (A should not be able to change her move) and perfectly conceiling (B should not be able to make a decision on his move, based on the move of A). As stated in Wikipedia, there is no such scheme, that fullfills both requirements, if A or B have unbounded computational resources.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of is to have the parties exchange hashes of their moves, then once both have the hashes, exchange the content. Producing hash collisions is not for the weak of pocket, Schneier passed along [an estimate that by 2015 it'd only take 2048 server-years](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/10/when_will_we_se.html) to produce a SHA1 collision.  So use SHA2.  Your game should be safe.

Comment: As I understand it, your method is a commitment scheme, that is perfectly binding, because neither A nor B should be able to compute a move that shares the same signature (so neither can change his/her mind). Your commitment scheme is not perfectly concealing, if the number of moves is small (B simply has to compute the signatures of all moves and compare it with the signature, that he has received from A, to determine what move A has made), so with your scheme the player, that moves second, has the upper hand in this case.

Comment: That's easily dealt with, if the moves are that constrained just include a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), say 16 bytes of random material  that will be ignored.